# What happens if I exceed my browser's ajax request limit?

Tags: ajax

Will it be smart and queue later requests for submission after earlier requests complete, or will it do something stupid like discard later requests which push it over its maximum number.

Is the answer the same across browsers, or does it vary?

Comment: What's this AJAX request limit?

Comment: He mean number of open connections from js a browser can handle. @morgancodes, are you trying to bruteforce or something? I've never heard of someone reach that limit with regular application.

Comment: @VOX I haven't run up against the limit, just curious about what would happen if I did. If there was potential for requests to be dropped, I'd want to protect against that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the fact that browsers typically limit the number of simultaneous connections to a particular host (2 is recommended by the HTTP spec)?  If so, then yes, all requests will be queued.  It's really no different then loading a web page that has a lot of images in it -- the initial load will result in a bunch of new requests, but they may have to wait based on the connection limit.  But all of your images do load.

I'm not aware of an ajax-specific request limit.

Comment: It's mostly 6 in modern browsers nowadays.